# C++ How to find class by it's name?

Tags: c++, linux, ld-preload

How can I find a class to call it's methods by knowing class name and method names?

Details:
I'm trying to write library to replace some functions from another program which is also written using C++ by LD_PRELOAD functionality.
I need to have an ability to call functions from program in which this library gonna be integrated.

Comment: You *do* know that symbols once passed through the compiler will be [*mangled*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)? That means a member function like e.g. `SomeClass::someFunction` will not simply be called that? The mangling scheme is not specified by the C++ specification, and depends on the compiler and its implementation. You need to know the mangled name of the functions you want to access.

Comment: Furthermore, C++ doesn't have [*type introspection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) and it's not possible to get "just" a class. You need to tell the system to get a pointer to a specific member function of some class, using the mangled name.

Comment: Still furthermore, remember that non-static member functions needs an object to be called on. This is usually passed as a hidden first argument to the member functions, and becomes the `this` pointer in the functions. If your function which overrides the loaded member function doesn't handle this special argument, your code will never work.

Comment: Does mangled name is looks like _ZNK4GNET5Skill8GetLevelEv ? I found this name in IDA PRO. May i find and call functions only knowing this type of names? Or maybe i need to find an address where this function located to call it at runtime? I need to know all possible ways how can i call these methods if i don't have a sources of the main program (i can just open it via IDA). Thanks.

Comment: Yes that's a typical mangled name. If you know this name, you can get a handle to the function and call it. ***However*** if it's non-static member function, then (as I said before) it needs an object to be called on. If you don't have an object of the right class, which is really impossible to get from a library or executable file, then you simply can not call it without expecting *undefined behavior*. If you have the header-files where the class is defined, then you can use that class-definition to create an object though.

Comment: Can you, please, provide some simple example how to call static function using it`s mangled name? And how can i rate up your answer? It's suppose to be the best.

Comment: Plain [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [`dlsym`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) should work fine then, providing the mangled name to `dlsym`.

Comment: In a word, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

C++ loses all class naming information during the compile process!

You can`t do something like:

```
Class.forName("MyClass");
```

Like you know it from Java.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class

This technique is called reflection and its not suported by C++
You can use a Framework (e.g. Boost) to help you out there, but the methods you want to call have to be declared and defined with this Framework.

Comment: May i use function names like this: _ZNK4GNET5Skill8GetLevelEv to call them from my library?

Comment: How are you going to handle the class initializers? And passing an implicit `this` to each method? I fear you've set yourself a really nasty job here :/

Comment: @LemanRass Dont ever do this, C++ doesnt support reflection and its a very bad idea to trying anyways. This is highly Compiler dependend and propably wont work on any other enviroment.

If the external library doesnt give you access to the method, you shouldnt use it!

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not support reflection so you cannot search for functions/classes by name after compile time.

It sounds like if possible the design needs to be reworked.  Ideally you should update the library to include what it needs from the programs. Either pull out the common logic from the programs into a third library - or put the functions that needs to be called by the programs into the current library and just pass the relevant data that will be manipulated into the library.

If this is not possible you can pass a function pointer from your programs into your library - this allows the library to have access to the functions it needs without any real knowledge of where it is coming from.

ie

```
void library_function1(std::function<void(int)> func)
{
     func(1);
}
```